# problems with htmlrows javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make htmlRows to work. When I select productcode I want to trigger func Choise() and fill price and name.

```
 <script>
            // get Product Code
        <?php
            $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=praktika", "root", "");
            function fill_productCode($connect)
            {
                $output = '';
                $query = "SELECT * FROM services";
                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute();
                $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                foreach ($result as $row) {
                    $output .= '<option value="' . $row["code"] . '">' . $row["code"] . '</option>';
                }
                return $output;
            }
            ?>


        var count = $(".itemRow").length;
        $(document).on('click', '#addRows', function() {
            count++;
            var htmlRows = '';

            htmlRows += '<tr>';
            htmlRows += '<td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>';
            htmlRows += '<td><select id="selectUsers" onChange="Choice();" type="text" name="productCode[]" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"><option value="">Select</option><?php echo fill_productCode($connect); ?></select></td>';
            // htmlRows += '<td><input type="text" id="serviceName" name="productName[]" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>';    
            htmlRows += '<td><input type="text" id="productName_' + count + '" name="productName[]" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>';
            htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_' + count + '" class="form-control quantity" autocomplete="off"></td>';
            htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_' + count + '" class="form-control price" autocomplete="off"></td>';
            htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_' + count + '" class="form-control total" autocomplete="off"></td>';
            htmlRows += '</tr>';
            $('#invoiceItem').append(htmlRows);
        });

     var serviceName = new Array();
    var price_1 = new Array();
    var ful = new Array();

    serviceName[0] = "";
    price_1[0] = "";
    ful[0] = "";

    serviceName[1] = "Serverių instaliavimas";
    price_1[1] = "544.99";
    ful[1] = "Buddy Smith";

    serviceName[2] = "Sąskaitų skaitmenizavimas";
    price_1[2] = "111";
    ful[2] = "Libbie Smith";

    serviceName[3] = 4;
    price_1[3] = "asmith";
    ful[3] = "Andy Smith";


    function Choice() {
      //x = document.getElementById("users");
      y = document.getElementById("selectUsers");

      //x.value = y.options[y.selectedIndex].text;
      document.getElementById("serviceName").value = serviceName[y.selectedIndex];
      document.getElementById("price_1").value = price_1[y.selectedIndex];
      document.getElementById("ful").value = ful[y.selectedIndex];
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Maybe `$('#invoiceItem').append($(htmlRows))` helps.

Comment: In your PHP portuion, you define a function yet never call it. Additionally, it is not good practice to mix PHP with JavaScript in this manner. It is best to move the PHP Script to it's own script and call it via AJAX.

Comment: I do call that function, in htmlrows in input. Im not good with ajax, and got no time to learn it now. gotta finish this work fast. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, it is best to move PHP script to their own page.

**PHP - getServices.php**

```
<?php
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=praktika", "root", "");
$statement = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM services");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$output = "";
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $output .= '<option value="' . $row["code"] . '">' . $row["code"] . '</option>' . "\r\n";
}
echo $output;
?>
```

You can then GET this via AJAX when needed.

```
$.get("getServices.php", function(h){
  $("#selectUsers").html(h);
});
```

This would make a GET Request and the PHP would output the HTML back to the request.

It would be better to set this more like an API. Where a GET request can get JSON data back and then manipulate as needed with jQuery.

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  function getData(page) {
    var results;
    $.getJSON(page, function(data) {
      results = data;
    });
    return results;
  }

  function addRow(tObj) {
    var c = $("tbody tr", tObj).length;
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    $("<td>").appendTo(newRow); // 0
    $("<input>", {
      class: "itemRow",
      type: "checkbox"
    }).appendTo($("td", newRow));
    $("<td>").appendTo(newRow); // 1
    var sUser = $("<select>", {
      id: "selectUsers",
      name: "productCode[]",
      class: "form-control",
      autocomplete: "off"
    }).appendTo($("td", newRow).eq(1));
    $("<option>").html("Select User").appendTo(sUser);
    // Populate User Options
    $.each(getData("getUsers.php"), function(i, u) {
      $("<option>", {
        value: u.code
      }).html(u.name).appendTo(sUser);
    });
    $("<td>").appendTo(newRow); // 2
    $("<input>", {
      type: "text",
      id: "productName_" + (c + 1),
      name: "productName[]",
      class: "form-control",
      autofill: "off"
    }).appendTo($("td", newRow).eq(2));
    $("<td>").appendTo(newRow); // 3
    $("<input>", {
      type: "number",
      id: "quantity_" + (c + 1),
      name: "quantity[]",
      class: "form-control quantity",
      autofill: "off"
    }).appendTo($("td", newRow).eq(3));
    $("<td>").appendTo(newRow); // 4
    $("<input>", {
      type: "number",
      id: "price_" + (c + 1),
      name: "price[]",
      class: "form-control price",
      autofill: "off"
    }).appendTo($("td", newRow).eq(4));
    $("<td>").appendTo(newRow); // 5
    $("<input>", {
      type: "number",
      id: "total_" + (c + 1),
      name: "total[]",
      class: "form-control total",
      autofill: "off"
    }).appendTo($("td", newRow).eq(5));
    tObj.append(newRow);
  }

  $(document).on('click', '#addRows', function() {
    addRow($("#invoiceItem"));
  });
});
```

This would be potential PHP code:

**PHP - getUsers.php**

```
<?php
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=praktika", "root", "");
$statement = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$output = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  array_push($output, $row);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output);
$statement = null;
$connect = null;
?>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for thise code. im not really understand this jquery. and the getusers part is not needed.
The thing i trying to get, is to add new row to table, with dropdown whitch has from services table code row. then item name input whitch auto fills after i select option from dropdown, and the same goes for price input. 
Maybe i should share all project files? i dont know how to explain everything.

Comment: @FPVMVP then you can just use the `$.get()` I provided in the first portion of my answer. You may also look at `.load()`.